# Natural translation for Wort-Bild-Marke

Tags: translation, phrase, german-to-english

One way I find reviewed human translations of non-dictionary words or phrases is to find the identical Wikipedia page in another language.

I came across [Wort-Bild-Marke](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wort-Bild-Marke), which has no "In anderen Sprachen" links.

[Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wort_Bild_Marke) defines it as

```
sowohl Schrift als auch grafische Elemente enthaltendes Logo
```

my translation

```
Logo containing both font and graphic elements
```

Other related DE wiki pages are

- [Logo (Zeichen)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_%28Zeichen%29) (Logo in English)
- [Marke (Recht)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marke_%28Recht%29) (Trademark in English)

**Is there a word in English that captures the meaning of Wort-Bild-Marke?** Or is *Logo* with some modifiers, i.e. Text-based logo?

Other online dictionaries have the terms without hyphens ([dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=wortbildmarke)), or doesn't exist ([dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=wort-bild-marke&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on)).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is essentially about hte English, not German language. Translation requests to English are on-topic only if the translation is needed to understand the German word. Beside this, the question might be on-topic (if rephrased properly, i.e. describing the term instead of asking for a translation) on English Language Learners.

Comment: I think, at least going by the Duden description, "Emblem" would be a good fit. I've never heard Wrt-Bild-Marke anywhere before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I consider this question off-topic here (because it is a question about English, not German): it is often worthwhile having a look at linguee.com, in particular for terms from economics, politics and law. There you can search through real-world texts together with their respective translations.

For "Wort-Bild-Marke" (or Wortbildmarke, that's essentially the same), you'll find

http://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/wortbildmarke.html

where the most often used term seems to be "word and figurative mark". This is also the term the German Patent Office uses in it's [English FAQ](http://dpma.de/english/trade_marks/faq/index.html#a20).